# Impact of theoretical physics on the Nazi regime and vice versa

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, historiography

I am currently investigating the impact of the theoretical physics community and its developments on the progression of the second world war and the Nazi regime. I have read Cornwell's book on Hitler's scientists, and other texts on the Manhattan Project. My question is can you recommend any other resources (preferably books) which are relevant to my investigation? I stress:

- Resources which present personal accounts or otherwise of the physics community under the Nazi regime are **not** what I am asking for. Rather I require resources which assess the impact of theoretical physics on the progression of the war so that I am analyze them.

Comment: I noticed I received a '-1.' Moderators please alert me on how I should improve my question; I normally frequent the physics S.E. Are resource recommendations allowed here?

Comment: Well, wikipedia may help you in some way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Physik

Comment: You could read the Help Center, which specifically states that resource requests are [out of scope](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Do you know where I could ask to find these resources? Or perhaps I could rephrase the question to ask about the historiography, and also add an addendum requesting citations in an answer?

Comment: @user1997744 what about google? or the library of the history department of a university (maybe in your case the physics department may have something as well)...

Comment: @jwenting: I've tried many different search queries with Google, and most of the results have been irrelevant.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a resource request